# When should I use Scala method & function

Tags: scala

e.g.

```
val f1 = (a:Int) => a+1
def f2 = (a:Int) => a+1
```

Seems they are quite inter-changeable, are there any specific use case which I should use a particular one?

Comment: This is not method versus function, but _value_ (`val`) versus _method_ (`def`). Method versus function would be `def f2(a: Int) = a+1` and `val f2 = (a: Int) => a+1`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically one would write the `def` version as:

```
def f2(a:Int) = a+1
```

If you write it they way you did, it's actually creating a method `f2` that, when called, constructs a new function closure.  So in both of your cases, you still have a function.  But in the first case, the function gets constructed only once and stored (as `f1`) for later use.  But in the second case, the function gets constructed every time `f2` is referenced, which is kind of a waste.

So when to prefer a function over a method?  Well, you can work with a function a bit more easily in certain situations.  Consider this case:

```
(1 to 3).map(f1 andThen f1)    // totally fine
(1 to 3).map(f2 andThen f1)    // "missing arguments" error
(1 to 3).map(f2 _ andThen f1)  // fixed by adding "_" after the method name
```

So `f1` is always a function and so you can call a method like `andThen` on it.  The variable `f2` represents a method, so it doesn't expect to be used like this; it always expects to be followed by arguments.  You can always turn a method into a function by following it with an underscore, but this can look a little ugly if it's not necessary.

Comment: To verify what dhg is saying, note that in the REPL `f1 eq f1` is true but `f2 eq f2` is false.